# Can't find installed modules in azure devops pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building stage pipeline (env prp, tests, code). Currently have faced the blocker. Seems like each stage is kindda individual process. My requirements.txt is being installed correctly but then test stage raises the ModuleNotFoundError. Appreciate any hints how to make it working :)

yaml:

```
trigger: none
parameters:
  - name: "input_files"
    type: object
    default: ['a-rg', 't-rg', 'd-rg', 'p-rg']

stages:
  - stage: 'Env_prep'
    jobs:
      - job: "install_requirements"
        steps:
          - script: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
  - stage: 'Tests'
    jobs:
      - job: 'Run_tests'
        steps:
          - script: |
              python -m pytest -v tests/variableGroups_tests.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different jobs and stages are capable of being executed on different agents in Azure Pipelines. In your case, the installation requirements are a direct prerequisite of the tests being run, so everything should be in one job:

```yaml
trigger: none
parameters:
  - name: "input_files"
    type: object
    default: ['a-rg', 't-rg', 'd-rg', 'p-rg']

stages:
  - stage: Test
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
          - script: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
            displayName: Install Required Components
          - script: |
              python -m pytest -v tests/variableGroups_tests.py
            displayName: Run Tests
```

Breaking those into separate script steps isn't even necessary unless you want the log output to be separate in the console.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to merge stages somehow? I mean I want ro run requirements.txt once and allow further stages to use it's modules.

Comment: Not really - in your original scenario, if you re-ran the pipeline, that installation stage would run again, so every time you trigger the pipeline it's going to happen. A better solution would be to alter your script to check for the presence of requirements.txt and only install if it's not there.